# 'If and then else if and then else' calculation

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a fairly complex (for me) If AND THEN calculation I'm trying to create and I could use some assistance.

[image: This image shows what I'm trying to do]

Here's the formula I'm using typed out:

```
=(if WhatIsYourVendorType = "Food Truck" and WhatSizeBoothDoYouNeed = "10' X 10'" then (PleaseSelectAllOfTheEventsYoureSigningUpFor_Value*20) else if WhatIsYourVendorType = "Food Truck" and WhatSizeBoothDoYouNeed = "10’ X 20’” then (PleaseSelectAllOfTheEventsYoureSigningUpFor_Value*25) else ”Make A Selection First”)
```

The problem is this error message I keep getting:

[image: Cognito error]

Finally, this formula worked great for a single 'If AND THEN ELSE' calculation...just can't get the additional 'ELSE IF's to work:

> = (if WhatIsYourVendorType = "Food Truck" and WhatSizeBoothDoYouNeed = "10' X 10'" then
>   (PleaseSelectAllOfTheEventsYoureSigningUpFor_Value*20) else "no")

Comment: Most of your text is actually in the images. That's a bad idea not only because it makes the text not searchable, but people who can't see the images (maybe their work network blocks them or they're visually impaired) can't get the information to help. Questions are better when they're self-contained and all of the information needed to answer them is in the text. Images should be for supplemental information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist on Cognito Forms but I can see several stuff here. I put in bold the things I think may help your formula.

=(if WhatIsYourVendorType = "Food Truck" and WhatSizeBoothDoYouNeed = "10' X 10'" then (PleaseSelectAllOfTheEventsYoureSigningUpFor_Value*20) else **(**if WhatIsYourVendorType = "Food Truck" and WhatSizeBoothDoYouNeed = "10’ X 20’” then (PleaseSelectAllOfTheEventsYoureSigningUpFor_Value*25) else **”**Make A Selection First**”)**)

Also check your quotes and if the calculation type result is set to text.